# How to sort ps output by process start time?

Tags: linux, mac-osx, unix, command-line-interface, process

Is there a way to sort ps output by process start time, so newest are either at the top or bottom ?

On Linux ?

On SysV5 ?

On Mac ?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

This should work on Linux and SysV5

```
ps -ef --sort=start_time
```

Comment: This works exactly as requested, thanks.

After more digging I am not sure this is possible on Mac OS without a bit of awk

Comment: start_time worked. lstart did not. RHEL

Comment: `ps aux --sort=start_time` command works fine

Comment: how to I reverse the order?

Comment: @PhuNguyen bit late to the party, but maybe someone else has a use for this. You can reverse the order by piping the output through `tac`.

Comment: How about keep watching the last 10 processes ?

Comment: @Stephane try this: `watch "ps -ef --sort=start_time | grep -v kworker | tail"`

Comment: My take `ps-recent() { watch "ps -ef --sort=start_time | tail -n $1"; }`

Comment: @PhuNguyen use a '-' before the key like --sort=-pid  '+' is redundant to the default

Answer (score 15):

Linux:

```
$ ps aux --sort=lstart
```

OSX:

```
$ ps aux -O started
```

Comment: I'm afraid neither of those sorts by start time. 

It does display the start time, but doesn't sort.

Comment: The difference between lstart and start_time caught me out as well -- `lstart` gives a full timestamp, but cannot be used as a sort key. `start_time` gives the usual 'time within the last 24 hours, date otherwise' column, and can be used as a sort key. Both give 'STARTED' in the header.

Comment: time within last hour: if a process was launched yesterday at a time later than today, it will appear after today's process ... can't be used by sort, unless a bit of "awk" changes that

Comment: @OlivierDulac: not for me. `15/12 15:40` appears before `16/12 15:39`, just as `13:39` appears before `15:38`.

Comment: lstart did not work for me. start_time did.

Comment: OS X 10.11: `ps: started: keyword not found`. `ps -L` gives `lstart` and `start`.

Answer (score 5):

Along with the great answers above, sometimes I just want to see the top 20 offenders by process sorted descending by time, cpu% and memory usage.

For that I use:

```
ps auxww --sort=lstart | sort -r -k3,4 | head -20
```

This would be on a CentOS platform, though I've enjoyed the same results on Fedora as well.

Oh and for grins, I sometimes want to remove a set of processes, so I simply use a variant on the above that includes a bit of grep -v action, such as:

```
ps auxww --sort=lstart | sort -r -k3,4 | grep -v "sbin/httpd" | head -20
```

Comment: `--sort` of `ps` does not work for me. Relying on shell `sort`. +1

Answer (score 4):

I can't comment yet, but to answer the question about how to reverse the order of a time sort, just put a minus sign (`-`) in front of the field.
Example: `ps -elf --sort=-start_time`

Answer (score 2):

Or try 'ls', as it allows time formats that are easy to sort, and easier to use.

```
( cd /proc; ls -td --full-time --time-style=+%s [0123456789]*; )
```

Outputs the date/time in epoch, newest procs at the top.

Comment: this only shows the pids

Answer (score 1):

Try simple command:

```
ps | sort -k7 -n
```

`-k7` for the time column and `-n` for numeric.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjQQp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's obsolete syntax, but I find it practical for brevity:

```
ps OT <other_options>
```

For example:

```
ps OT ax
```